# Can you make your public_html more organized by making separate files for your different type of files in your website?

Tags: php, html, cpanel

Hi guys so I was wondering...what if I make my website files even more organized in cPanel. So I already have folders inside my public_html like, 'images' 'videos' 'css' 'js' but I don't have a folder for only my html files and another just for my php files, would my website still run properly if I did so? What I mean by this is, would the browser still recognize my index.html as the first one and my other pages aswell? The reason why I want to do this is simply just to organize things...also should I convert all my pages to to PHP files instead of some html and some php, should I conver the html files into php even when they don't need any php? Or should I carry on having some html and some php files?

Comment: Keep your index.html in your root and yes you can add as many folders as you would like. This question might be of topic but I'm sure you'll get enough comments to answer your question.

Comment: read about MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the file that are accessible via `https://youdomain/somepage.(php|html)/` needs to be at the root of your website, especially your `index.html` file. Otherwise, you could access your files via `https://yourdomain/folder/page.html`.

There is also a possibility to make apache look into a folder for a file, using your apache config but this is a little bit more complicated. [see here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/urlmapping.html)

If you are accessing PHP file via reference ( such as `require_once` ), as long as the reference are still correct, everything should be fine.

Comment: So then I am able to in the root of my website, which for me is public_html, add a folder named 'html-files' and there would be no problem...even my index.html would be able to go in there?

Comment: Depending on the solution you choose, yes. It is usually a good idea to leave your `index.html` in the root of the server, but with the correct directory mapping, you could.